# Shutdown Ubuntu 12.04 Desktops on network by a script?

Tags: shutdown

I have 5 Ubuntu 12.04 desktops connected by network , can i make a script to  shutdown

them from my laptop that also  have Ubuntu 12.04 ?

So that make it easy and reduce time and effort to shutdown them locally .

I don't need to connect to each user manually by ssh and write down each username and

password every time .

Any Help ?

Comment: While you wait for a proper answer, you could google "ssh expect"

Comment: this community is share our problems , and share answers with other , am searching man but i like to share solutions

Comment: :) No harm was intended! I just know 'expect' is what fixes it but I can't provide the proper script

Comment: my question is can i have a user to shutdown them all not every machine by its user

Comment: So you would run one command from your laptop which starts a script. And in that script you would already have stored the hostnames / IPs of the other machiens you want to shutdown? And the script would connect to each in turn, automatically, and tell them to shutdown without asking you for the password?

Comment: is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, using 'expect'. I'm a rubbish scripter so bear with me :)

Comment: ok am waiting your script man hahaha i like to share it also

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12657/discussion-between-a-j-rossington-and-nux)

Comment: Is there a solution?

Comment: There is no need to use expect.  See @davidbaumann's answer below, and the comment.  Use ssh-keygen, then ssh-copy-id -i ~/ssh/id_rsa.pub <remote computer> - then you don't need to enter passwords afterwards. No reason to use expect ever...

Comment: I use init 0 for shutdowns.  It flushes the buffers so the directories are safe, and is quick.  Shutdown uses it also, but only after notifying all the tty  ports and waiting for users to react.  Which makes no sense if you don't have multiple users on your Pi.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `ssh` (see `man ssh`). For each machine it will be a command something like:

```
ssh [-l login_name] [user@]hostname sudo shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSH in a script in order to shutdown these machines.
Just create a .sh file containing lines linke in tje solution of Radu.

In order to do this automatically, you can use ssh-copy-id, so you will not have to enter the password every time.

Comment: Yes.  Use ssh-keygen, then ssh-copy-id -i ~/ssh/id_rsa.pub <remote computer> - then you don't need to enter passwords afterwards.  No reason to use expect.